# Django - Save multiple versions of an Image

Tags: python, django, forms, image, modeling

My application needs to save multiple versions of an uploaded Image. One high quality image and another one just for thumbnails use (low quality).
Currently this is working most of the time but sometimes the save method simply fails and all of my Thumbnail images are getting deleted, especially then if I use the remove_cover checkbox at my form

> raise ValueError("The '%s' attribute has no file associated with it."
> % self.field.name) app                  | ValueError: The
> 'postcover_tn' attribute has no file associated with it.

-> See full trace here: https://pastebin.com/hgieMGet

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField()
    content = models.TextField(blank=False)
    postcover = models.ImageField(
        verbose_name="Post Cover",
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        upload_to=image_uploads,
    )
    postcover_tn = models.ImageField(
        verbose_name="Post Cover Thumbnail",
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        upload_to=image_uploads,
    )
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.postcover:
            if not (self.postcover_tn and os.path.exists(self.postcover_tn.path)):
                image = Image.open(self.postcover)
                outputIoStream = BytesIO()
                baseheight = 500
                hpercent = baseheight / image.size[1]
                wsize = int(image.size[0] * hpercent)
                imageTemproaryResized = image.resize((wsize, baseheight))
                imageTemproaryResized.save(outputIoStream, format='PNG')
                outputIoStream.seek(0)
                self.postcover = InMemoryUploadedFile(outputIoStream, 'ImageField',
                                                      "%s.png" % self.postcover.name.split('.')[0], 'image/png',
                                                      sys.getsizeof(outputIoStream), None)
                image = Image.open(self.postcover)
                outputIoStream = BytesIO()
                baseheight = 175
                hpercent = baseheight / image.size[1]
                wsize = int(image.size[0] * hpercent)
                imageTemproaryResized = image.resize((wsize, baseheight))
                imageTemproaryResized.save(outputIoStream, format='PNG')
                outputIoStream.seek(0)
                self.postcover_tn = InMemoryUploadedFile(outputIoStream, 'ImageField',
                                                      "%s.png" % self.postcover.name.split('.')[0], 'image/png',
                                                      sys.getsizeof(outputIoStream), None)
        elif self.postcover_tn:
            self.postcover_tn.delete()

        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

It also seems that I'm not able to properly resolve:

- self.postcover_tn.delete() -> Unresolved attribute reference 'delete' for class 'InMemoryUploadedFile'
- self.postcover_tn.path -> Unresolved attribute reference 'path' for class 'InMemoryUploadedFile'

forms.py:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    instance = super(PostForm, self).save(commit=False)
    if self.cleaned_data.get('remove_cover'):
        try:
            os.unlink(instance.postcover.path)
        except OSError:
            pass
        instance.postcover = None
    if commit:
        instance.save()
    return instance
```

Comment: Have you considered using [sorl_thumbnail](https://github.com/jazzband/sorl-thumbnail) for this? It will generate whatever size you need on the fly and cache it for use later. Works with the `ImageField`. This way you don't need to worry about resizing and save errors.

Comment: Not really but to me this looks like that a image always gets generated on the fly. If so, this would hurt my CPU as i process images with every request I have on my platform. So i thought generating a pre-processed image is a better alternative here. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It only gets generated once, then it's saved to a cache folder. Every time that image + size is called it checks if it exists first. When I said on the fly, I meant you can use the template tag settings to generate any dimensions you want.

Comment: Ahh okay cool, thanks for this advice :D.

Comment: But in some way this does still not solve my problem if i want to remove a postcover like shown in my forms.py this still fails or at least it unlinks all postcover until i save a new one for some reason.

Comment: Issues Fixed! Had nothing to do we the question from above

Comment: just curious, why you are not using `signals` to handle images (creating multiple versions, updating, deleting ..) and thus leaving `save()` method thinner and plz can you share with us `image_uploads` function

Answer (score 11, accepted):

maybe if we look at the problem from another angle, we could solve it otherwise, out of the box. `signals` are very handy when it comes to handle images (add, update and delete) and below how i managed to solve your issue:

in `models.py`:

```
# from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify


class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField()
    # slug = models.SlugField('slug', max_length=255,
        # unique=True, null=True, blank=True,
        # help_text='If blank, the slug will be generated automatically from the given title.'
    # )
    content = models.TextField(blank=False)

    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    # rename images with the current post id/pk (which is UUID) and keep the extension
    # for cover thumbnail we append "_thumbnail" to the name 

    # e.g: 
    # img/posts/77b122a3d241461b80c51adc41d719fb.jpg
    # img/posts/77b122a3d241461b80c51adc41d719fb_thumbnail.jpg

    def upload_cover(instance, filename):
        ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
        filename = '{}.{}'.format(instance.id, ext)
        path = 'img/posts/'
        return '{}{}'.format(path, filename)

    postcover = models.ImageField('Post Cover',
        upload_to=upload_cover,  # callback function
        null=True, blank=True,
        help_text=_('Upload Post Cover.')
    )

    def upload_thumbnail(instance, filename):
        ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
        filename = '{}_thumbnail.{}'.format(instance.id, ext)
        path = 'img/posts/'
        return '{}{}'.format(path, filename)

    postcover_tn = models.ImageField('Post Cover Thumbnail',
        upload_to=upload_thumbnail,  # callback function
        null=True, blank=True,
        help_text=_('Upload Post Cover Thumbnail.')
    )

    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    published_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # i moved the logic to signals

        # if not self.slug:
            # self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

create new file and rename it `signals.py` (near to `models.py`):

```
import io
import sys

from PIL import Image

from django.core.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save, pre_delete

from .models import Post

#  DRY
def image_resized(image, h):
    name = image.name
    _image = Image.open(image)
    content_type = Image.MIME[_image.format]
    r = h / _image.size[1]  # ratio
    w = int(_image.size[0] * r)
    imageTemproaryResized = _image.resize((w, h))
    file = io.BytesIO()
    imageTemproaryResized.save(file, _image.format)
    file.seek(0)
    size = sys.getsizeof(file)
    return file, name, content_type, size


@receiver(pre_save, sender=Post, dispatch_uid='post.save_image')
def save_image(sender, instance, **kwargs):

    # add image (cover | thumbnail)
    if instance._state.adding:

        #  postcover
        file, name, content_type, size = image_resized(instance.postcover, 500)
        instance.postcover = InMemoryUploadedFile(file, 'ImageField', name, content_type, size, None)

        #  postcover_tn
        file, name, content_type, size = image_resized(instance.postcover_tn, 175)
        instance.postcover_tn = InMemoryUploadedFile(file, 'ImageField', name, content_type, size, None)


    # update image (cover | thumbnail)
    if not instance._state.adding:
        # we have 2 cases:
        # - replace old with new
        # - delete old (when 'clear' checkbox is checked)

        #  postcover
        old = sender.objects.get(pk=instance.pk).postcover
        new = instance.postcover
        if (old and not new) or (old and new and old.url != new.url):
            old.delete(save=False)

        #  postcover_tn
        old = sender.objects.get(pk=instance.pk).postcover_tn
        new = instance.postcover_tn
        if (old and not new) or (old and new and old.url != new.url):
            old.delete(save=False)


@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Post, dispatch_uid='post.delete_image')
def delete_image(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    s = sender.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)

    if (not s.postcover or s.postcover is not None) and (not s.postcover_tn or s.postcover_tn is not None):
        s.postcover.delete(False)
        s.postcover_tn.delete(False)
```

in `apps.py`:

we need to register signals in `apps.py` since we use decorators `@receiver`:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class BlogConfig(AppConfig):  # change to the name of your app
    name = 'blog'  # and here
    verbose_name = _('Blog Entries')

    def ready(self):
        from . import signals
```

and this is the first screen shot of `post` admin area

[image]

since the thumbnail is generated from post cover, as UI/UX good practices there's no need to show a second input file for post cover thumbnail (i kept the second image field read only in `admin.py`).

below is the second screenshot after i uploaded the image

PS: the screenshot is taken from another app that i'm working on, so there's little changes, in your case you should see

- **Post Cover** instead **Featured Image**
- `Currently: img/posts/8b0be417db564c53ad06cb493029e2ca.jpg` (see `upload_cover()` in  `models.py`) instead  `Currently: img/blog/posts/featured/8b0be417db564c53ad06cb493029e2ca.jpg`

[image]

in `admin.py`

```
# "img/posts/default.jpg" and "img/posts/default_thumbnail.jpg" are placeholders
# grab to 2 image placeholders from internet and put them under "/static" folder

def get_post_cover(obj):
    src = obj.postcover.url if obj.postcover and \
    hasattr(obj.postcover, 'url') else os.path.join(
        settings.STATIC_URL, 'img/posts/default.jpg')
    return mark_safe('<img src="{}" height="500" style="border:1px solid #ccc">'.format(src))
get_post_cover.short_description = ''
get_post_cover.allow_tags = True

def get_post_cover_thumbnail(obj):
    src = obj.postcover_tn.url if obj.postcover_tn and \
    hasattr(obj.postcover_tn, 'url') else os.path.join(
        settings.STATIC_URL, 'img/posts/default_thumbnail.jpg')
    return mark_safe('<img src="{}" height="175" style="border:1px solid #ccc">'.format(src))
get_post_cover_thumbnail.short_description = ''
get_post_cover_thumbnail.allow_tags = True


class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', .. )
    fields = (
        'author', 'title', 'content',
        get_post_cover, get_post_cover_thumbnail, 'postcover',
    )
    readonly_fields = (get_post_cover, get_post_cover_thumbnail)

[..]
```

and finally you don't need any **delete** logic in `save()` function in `forms.py`